# Another Activity starts on its own

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Recently I noticed that my app is not showing the materialAlertDialog. When I checked further. This is what is happening:

When a user signs up then I show a custom alert dialog containing a progress bar but as soon as the sign up process is complete another Alert Dialog is supposed to appear but instead of that the MainActivity starts over it. And i have to press the back button in order to get back to the SignUpActivity and then there is my Dialog being shown.

Also many times before I could press the back button the app would have already crashed.

Here is what I received on debugging:

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.infinitystudios.quinovi.RegisterActivity has leaked window DecorView@fb7a1bb[RegisterActivity] that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:1049)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:1023)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:450)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:114)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:505)
        at com.infinitystudios.quinovi.RegisterActivity.StartAccountCreation(RegisterActivity.java:152)
        at com.infinitystudios.quinovi.RegisterActivity.ValidateData(RegisterActivity.java:95)
        at com.infinitystudios.quinovi.RegisterActivity.lambda$onCreate$0$RegisterActivity(RegisterActivity.java:45)
        at com.infinitystudios.quinovi.-$$Lambda$RegisterActivity$9UObv7lMX3EKvsR9ZGkbBlnv9b0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
```

And:

```
--------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.infinitystudios.quinovi, PID: 12215
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=DecorView@fb7a1bb[RegisterActivity] not attached to window manager
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:604)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:508)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:146)
        at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:676)
        at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:658)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialog.dismiss(AppCompatDialog.java:140)
        at com.infinitystudios.quinovi.RegisterActivity.lambda$null$2$RegisterActivity(RegisterActivity.java:171)
        at com.infinitystudios.quinovi.-$$Lambda$RegisterActivity$NZHJI1-9H-gfMUEP6ocbSxiYFnk.onSuccess(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
```

I did see try the solution which said to show the dialog only if the Activity is not finishing but:

(1) in that case the dialog never appears and it is important to show the dialog
(2) the MainActivity still pops into the screen

**UPDATE:**

My SignUp/RegisterActivity

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseFirestore firestore;

    private Button signUpBtn;
    private TextView signInTxt;
    private TextInputLayout passTil, cpassTil;
    private TextInputEditText nameTxtbx, emailTxtbx, passTxtbx, cpassTxtbx;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        init();

        signUpBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> ValidateData());

        signInTxt.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();

        });

    }

    private void init() {

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        signUpBtn = findViewById(R.id.ra_signup_btn);
        signInTxt = findViewById(R.id.ra_signin_txt);
        passTil = findViewById(R.id.ra_password_til);
        cpassTil = findViewById(R.id.ra_cpassword_til);
        nameTxtbx = findViewById(R.id.ra_name_tiet);
        emailTxtbx = findViewById(R.id.ra_email_tiet);
        passTxtbx = findViewById(R.id.ra_password_tiet);
        cpassTxtbx = findViewById(R.id.ra_cpassword_tiet);

    }

    private void ValidateData() {

        HideSoftKeyboard();

        String name, email, pass, cpass;

        name = Objects.requireNonNull(nameTxtbx.getText()).toString().trim();
        email = Objects.requireNonNull(emailTxtbx.getText()).toString().trim();
        pass = Objects.requireNonNull(passTxtbx.getText()).toString().trim();
        cpass = Objects.requireNonNull(cpassTxtbx.getText()).toString().trim();

        if (!name.isEmpty()) {

            if (!email.isEmpty()) {

                if (email.contains("@") && email.contains(".")) {

                    if (!pass.isEmpty()) {

                        if (pass.length() >= 6) {

                            if (cpass.equals(pass)) {

                                StartAccountCreation(name, email, pass);

                            } else {

                                cpassTil.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.cpass_not_match));
                                cpassTxtbx.requestFocus();

                            }

                        } else {

                            passTil.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.password_greater));
                            passTxtbx.requestFocus();

                        }

                    } else {

                        passTil.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.field_required));
                        passTxtbx.requestFocus();

                    }

                } else {

                    emailTxtbx.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.valid_email));
                    emailTxtbx.requestFocus();

                }

            } else {

                emailTxtbx.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.field_required));
                emailTxtbx.requestFocus();

            }

        } else {

            nameTxtbx.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.field_required));
            nameTxtbx.requestFocus();

        }

    }

    private void StartAccountCreation(String name, String email, String pass) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this, R.style.CustomAlertDialogTheme);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary_progress_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        HandleOrientation(true);

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                .addOnSuccessListener(authResult ->

                        Objects.requireNonNull(auth.getCurrentUser()).sendEmailVerification()
                                .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {

                                    String CAID = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                                    HashMap<String, Object> accountMap = new HashMap<>();
                                    accountMap.put("date", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
                                    accountMap.put("name", name);

                                    firestore.collection("Accounts").document(CAID).set(accountMap)
                                            .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid1 -> {
                                                HandleOrientation(false);
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                                CreateDialog();
                                            })
                                            .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                                                HandleOrientation(false);
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            });

                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                                    HandleOrientation(false);
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }))

                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    HandleOrientation(false);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                });

    }

    private void HideSoftKeyboard() {

        RegisterActivity activity = RegisterActivity.this;

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view == null)
            view = new View(activity);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }

    private void HandleOrientation(boolean intention) {

        RegisterActivity activity = RegisterActivity.this;

        if (intention) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
        } else {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
        }

    }

    private void CreateDialog() {

        new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(RegisterActivity.this)
                .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.verification_sent))
                .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.verification_sent_msg))
                .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
                .show();

    }
```

**Update 2:**

I found out that this only happens when using the app in portrait mode. I always see the dialog appear in landscape but in portrait mode it won't show up, then it would start the main activity and crash immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the dialog on Sign up activity. Also the context to dialog should be by activity name otherwise this exception occurs

E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked:

Please share your activity code for further help

Comment: I have added the code. Please Help
@PriyankaSinghal

Comment: The dialog you are showing has login code also. You should have the dialog with Yes button and on Yes click login the user or perform desired option